# Reference class instance in function provided to super()

Tags: javascript, inheritance, this, super, es6-class

Suppose I have the following super class:

```
class Super {
    constructor(printMyName) {
        this.name = 'Fred';
        printMyName();
    }
}
```

And a class that extends it:

```
class Child extends Super {
    constructor() {
        super(() => {
            console.log(this.name);
        });
    }
}
```

This is erroneous because my child class attempts to reference an instance field prior to super construction - the "this" keyword is not available until after `super()` has been called.

How can I make use of instance fields in methods I provide to `super`?

**EDIT**

As @Bergi rightly pointed out, this scenario does not make sense in its current form. My actual scenario is slightly more complicated because the function I am providing to `super` is run asynchronously and should therefore have instance data available to it. This includes instance fields declared in the parent and child classes.

To minimize changes to my original example, let's add a setTimeout to make the function run asynchronously:

```
class Super {
    constructor(printMyFullName) {
        this.firstName = 'Fred';
        setTimeout(printMyFullName, 10000);
    }
}
```

And let's allow the child class to set its own instance field following its call to `super`:

```
class Child extends Super {
    constructor(opts) {
        super(() => {
            console.log('%s %s', this.firstName, this.lastName);
        });

        this.lastName = 'Savage';
    }
}
```

The question still applies, but I'll clarify: How can I make use of **child and parent** instance data in a function provided to `super`?

Comment: Don't pass methods to `super`. Why would you do that? Just write `super(); console.log(this.name);`. If you have a real-world use case, please tell us more about your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: Sure. I have a `ConfirmationDialog` super class that renders dialog content provided to it via its constructor. By default, it has 2 buttons, "Confirm" and "Cancel". The class accepts an `onConfirm` param in its constructor. I also have an `ExportDialog` class that extends `ConfirmationDialog`. In its constructor, I'm calling `super` on `ConfirmationDialog` and providing its `onConfirm` param. B/c the `onConfirm` function is run asynchronously when the user confirms the dialog, it makes sense for instance data to be available to it. So I'd like `onConfirm` to be able to reference the instance.

Comment: If it's run asynchronously, not called synchronously from within the superclass constructor as in your question, using `this` in the arrow function just works. (That said, I would recommend not to render anything from within a constructor)

Comment: I'm not sure `this` just works, as you said. When I attempt to use `this` as I wrote in my edit above, I get the following error: `TypeError: attempted to get private field on non-instance`.

Comment: There are no private fields in the code you posted. Running the code works as expected.